# vuejs page doesn't refresh automatically using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm using `vue.js`, and I want to use `webpack-dev-server` to refresh page automatically when I modify the `vue.js` file, but I have to refresh page by myself.

**vue**:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
var myComponent = Vue.extend({
  template:"<div>hello vue template</div>"
});
Vue.component('my-component',myComponent);
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

**html**:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry:['webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
'webpack/hot/only-dev-server','./src/vue/main.js'],
    output:{
        path: __dirname + '/dist/js',
        filename:'vue.bundle.js',
        publicPath:'/public'
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.jsx?$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                loaders:["babel"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                loader:'style!css'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            },
            {
                test:/\.(jpg|png)$/,
                loader:'url'
            }
        ]
    },
     resolve: {
        root: [process.cwd() + '/src', process.cwd() + '/node_modules'],
        alias: {},
     extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue','.css', '.scss', '.ejs', '.png','.jpg']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('This file is created by laoqiren')
    ]
 };
```

**server.js**:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,
  stats:{colors:true},
  historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('Listening at localhost:8080');
});
```

I need your help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hot module relaoding does not reload the page. It reloads the module which changed. In this case, webpack-dev-server will reload the vue file and swap it with version your app was using (while the app is running)

Comment: and then How to reload page automatically?

Comment: improved explanation and formating

Comment: @laoqiren instead of using live reloading (refreshing page), you should be using hot module reloading (module refresh). Hot module reload is superior to live reloading